# Why are negatively charged ligands behind the neutral ligands in spectrochemical series?

Tags: coordination-compounds

I had doubt that shouldn't negatively charged ligands be better electron pair donors than neutral ligands like $\ce{CO}$ or $\ce{PPh3}$. But its not so. Why?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. I improved the formatting of your posts by using MathJax; for more information on how to do so yourself, visit the [help], [this meta-post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/7475) or [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/444/7475).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are confused by what the spectrochemical series actually shows. It is *not* a rating of stronger or less strong ligands to mean they can bind more or less strongly to the metal. It is *only* a rating of which ligands induce a high crystal field split in the resulting complex.

The splitting derives from the metal $\mathrm{e_g}$ orbitals — $\mathrm{d}_{x^2 - y^2}$ and $\mathrm{d}_{z^2}$ — actually being antibonding to the metal-ligand interaction and thus higher in energy than the (unmodified in a complex with only σ type interactions) $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbitals.

For systems more complex, i.e. including π interactions, the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbitals (the other three d-orbitals) interact in a π manner with ligand p-orbitals. If the ligand has populated p-orbitals such as halides have, the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ energy is raised as it is turned into a slightly antibonding interaction (the bonding one being on the ligands’ side). Since this brings $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ closer to $\mathrm{e_g}$, the field split is *reduced* and the ligands are termed *weak-field* ligands. In simplified Lewis schemes, one could represent this by a double forwards bond from the ligands to the metal.

In the case of *empty* p-type orbitals such as in $\ce{CO}$, metal to ligand back-bonding can occur by populated *metal* orbitals interacting with *unfilled* ligand orbitals; now it is the *metal’s* side of things that is stabilised. Since this π backbonding stabilises the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbitals, their energy is *lowered* and the field split becomes *greater.* Hence they are termed *strong-field* ligands. In simplified Lewis structures one could represent that by drawing a donor-acceptor arrow from the ligand to the metal (σ forwards bond) and one the other way (π back bond).

This all has *nothing* to do with the overall strength of metal-ligand interaction, as I mentioned earlier. In fact, strong complexes are typically obtained for *certain metal-ligand combinations* and the same ligand can be very bad in interacting with other metals. Classic example: $\ce{CO}$ ligands are *extremely* good at stabilising low metal oxidation states such as in $\ce{[Fe(CO)4]^2-}$, while they are rather lousy in stabilising high ones: $\ce{[Fe(CO)6]^2+}$ can only be synthesised in the extreme absence of all other ligands, i.e. in $\ce{SbF5}$ from $\ce{FeF2}$ where the fluorides will be drawn towards antimony to generate the even more stable $\ce{[SbF6]-}$ complex.